# Unable to insert data into a certain table

Tags: sql, sql-server, exception, sql-server-2012

So I am literally a new DBA and my machine has not been properly setup yet so every time someone sends in a request for an unknown error I am in charge of searching google for answers (hopefully changes by next week! sigh). So after searching on the internet for the past 2 hours I have yet to know what is causing the error that one of the guy sent to me. We are running sql server 2012 and we’re on patch level SP2/CU2.

The error message is

```
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Cannot insert data into CertainLog table. 

dbo.usp_insertcertainlog - EXECUTEPROCEDURE raisedSystem.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Instancesomething306(ROOT:certainwebsite.somewebsite.com)
```

The error occurs repeatedly in the certainwebsite.somewebsite.com webservice.

Here is a sample stack trace

```
> at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception,
> Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior,
> SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream,
> BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject
> stateObj, Boolean& dataReady) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds,
> RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean
> async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior
> cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String
> method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task,
> Boolean asyncWrite) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.InternalExecuteNonQuery(TaskCompletionSource`1
> completion, String methodName, Boolean sendToPipe, Int32 timeout,
> Boolean asyncWrite) at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery() at
> Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.DoExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand
> command) at
> Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand
> command) at
> Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Database.ExecuteNonQuery(DbCommand
> command)
```

Comment: Can you provide the insert statement being run?

Comment: We'll need to see " dbo.usp_insertcertainlog "...edit your post and update it with the code there?  also...which sql server version are you on?  2008?  2012?

Comment: i alreay provided the version of the sql server. It is sql server 2012 on patch sp2/cu2

Answer (score 0):

From the error it appears that account does not have access to insert data. You will need to modify the permissions.